# Range input with value greater than 100

Tags: html, input, range

I have the following code:

```js
document.querySelector('.target').value = 250;
console.log(document.querySelector('.target').value);
```

```html
<input type="range" class="target">
```

Console log prints `100` instead of `250`. Why, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to set the `max` attribute to something bigger then the default of `100`

```js
document.querySelector('.target').value = 250;
console.log(document.querySelector('.target').value);
```

```html
<input type="range" class="target" max="250">
```